# MySQl Subquery output with null data

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a MySQL database with vehicles, issued_fuel and mileage data (vs issued fuel) and want to get the following desired output.

### Desired Output

I want to get results including above related data as follows :

```
+---------------+------------+------------+---------+----------+
| registered_no | issue_date |    date    | mileage | fuel_qty |
+---------------+------------+------------+---------+----------+
| SP KR-3503    | 2021-02-22 | null       | null    |       40 |
| SP KR-3503    | 2021-02-26 | null       | null    |       30 |
| null          | 2021-03-03 | null       | null    |       40 |
| null          | 2021-03-15 | null       | null    |       45 |
| SP KR-3503    | 2021-03-18 | null       | null    |       40 |
| null          | 2021-03-25 | null       | null    |       45 |
| null          | 2021-04-04 | null       | null    |       35 |
| SP KE-6794    | 2021-04-25 | 2021-04-25 | 150     |       40 |
+---------------+------------+------------+---------+----------+
```

Because the table "tbl_trip_details" includes only one mileage (150km) for vehicle_no "SP KE-6794 for the date 2021-04-25.
My tables as follows :

### tbl_vehicle

```
+------------+---------------+--------+
| vehicle_id | registered_no | status |
+------------+---------------+--------+
|          1 | SP KR-3503    |      1 |
|          2 | SP KE-6794    |      1 |
+------------+---------------+--------+
```

### tbl_trip_details

```
+---------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
| trip_id | vehicle_id |    date    | mileage | status |
+---------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|       1 |          1 | 2021-04-25 |     125 |      1 |
|       2 |          1 | 2021-04-26 |     100 |      1 |
|       3 |          2 | 2021-04-25 |     150 |      1 |
+---------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
```

### tbl_direct_fuel

```
+----------------+---------+------------+
| direct_fuel_id | vehicle | issue_date |
+----------------+---------+------------+
|              1 |       1 | 2021-02-22 |
|              2 |       1 | 2021-02-26 |
|              3 |       3 | 2021-03-03 |
|              4 |       3 | 2021-03-15 |
|              5 |       1 | 2021-03-18 |
|              6 |       3 | 2021-03-25 |
|              7 |       3 | 2021-04-04 |
|              8 |       2 | 2021-04-25 |
+----------------+---------+------------+
```

### tbl_direct_fuel_details

```
+-----------------------------+----------------+------+----------+
| tbl_deirect_fuel_details_id | direct_fuel_id | item | fuel_qty |
+-----------------------------+----------------+------+----------+
|                           1 |              1 |    1 |       40 |
|                           2 |              2 |    1 |       30 |
|                           3 |              3 |    1 |       40 |
|                           4 |              4 |    1 |       45 |
|                           5 |              5 |    1 |       40 |
|                           6 |              6 |    1 |       45 |
|                           7 |              7 |    1 |       35 |
|                           8 |              8 |    1 |       40 |
+-----------------------------+----------------+------+----------+
```

I used the following query

```
select tv.registered_no, df.issue_date, td.date, td.mileage, df.fuel_qty
        from tbl_trip_details trip
        left join tbl_vehicle tv on tv.vehicle_id=trip.vehicle_id            
        join (select tbl_direct_fuel.direct_fuel_id, tbl_vehicle.registered_no, tbl_direct_fuel.vehicle, tbl_direct_fuel.issue_date, item,  tbl_direct_fuel_details.fuel_qty, tbl_direct_fuel_details.fuel_price 
            from tbl_direct_fuel_details
            left join tbl_direct_fuel on tbl_direct_fuel_details.direct_fuel_id = tbl_direct_fuel.direct_fuel_id
            join tbl_vehicle on tbl_vehicle.vehicle_id = tbl_direct_fuel.vehicle 
            where tbl_direct_fuel.status=1
            order by tbl_vehicle.registered_no 
            ) AS df on df.vehicle = tv.vehicle_id          
                    
        join (select tbl_trip_details.trip_id, tbl_vehicle.registered_no, tbl_trip_details.vehicle_id, tbl_trip_details.date, tbl_trip_details.mileage
            from tbl_trip_details            
            left join tbl_vehicle on tbl_vehicle.vehicle_id = tbl_trip_details.vehicle_id 
            where tbl_trip_details.status=1 
            order by tbl_vehicle.registered_no) AS td on td.vehicle_id = tv.vehicle_id
```

Since the date & mileage are repeated for other records and didn't get the expected result. So the query outs the following output:

```
+---------------+------------+------------+---------+----------+
| registered_no | issue_date |    date    | mileage | fuel_qty |
+---------------+------------+------------+---------+----------+
| SP KR-3503    | 2021-02-22 | 2021-04-25 |     150 |       40 |
| SP KR-3503    | 2021-02-26 | 2021-04-25 |     150 |       30 |
| null          | 2021-03-03 | 2021-04-25 |     150 |       40 |
| null          | 2021-03-15 | 2021-04-25 |     150 |       45 |
| SP KR-3503    | 2021-03-18 | 2021-04-25 |     150 |       40 |
| null          | 2021-03-25 | 2021-04-25 |     150 |       45 |
| null          | 2021-04-04 | 2021-04-25 |     150 |       35 |
| SP KE-6794    | 2021-04-25 | 2021-04-25 |     150 |       40 |
+---------------+------------+------------+---------+----------+
```

What may be going wrong in my query ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: Please add an example: source tables as CREATE TABLE, sample data as INSERT INTO, desired output for this sample data.

Comment: Judging from the end result, it seems like some part of the query are not necessary. Assuming that the combination of `registered_no` and `issue_date` are unique, you just need to make that as your left (fixed reference) table in `LEFT JOIN` then work out how to get result for the remaining columns.

Comment: If you change the last `join` to `left join` and change `AS td on td.vehicle_id = tv.vehicle_id` to `AS td on td.vehicle_id = tv.vehicle_id AND df.issue_Date=td.date` then ther esult might be correct. But If you provide more details about your source, then I think this query can be written much shorter.

Comment: @  Akina &  Luuk. Added sample data.

Comment: @ Akina & Luuk. Outputs also changed

Comment: `tbl_direct_fuel.status` and `tbl_direct_fuel_details.fuel_price` columns and data value don't have in sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT tv.registered_no, tdf.issue_date, ttd.date, ttd.mileage, tdfd.fuel_qty
   FROM tbl_direct_fuel tdf 
   LEFT JOIN tbl_vehicle tv 
          ON tdf.vehicle=tv.vehicle_id
   LEFT JOIN tbl_trip_details ttd 
          ON tdf.vehicle=ttd.vehicle_id 
         AND tdf.issue_date=ttd.date
   LEFT JOIN tbl_direct_fuel_details tdfd 
          ON tdf.direct_fuel_id=tdfd.direct_fuel_id;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ebc33380b581cacf405100fc7b7c1927)

Rather than having two separate sub-queries, I try to directly get the result with a bunch of LEFT JOINs. From what I can see in the updated expected result, `tbl_direct_fuel` is enough to be the reference table for all the others. I's just a matter of figuring the correct `ON` condition.

Also, I mentioned about the missing `tbl_direct_fuel.status` and `tbl_direct_fuel_details.fuel_price` from the sample data. I'm not concerned about `tbl_direct_fuel_details.fuel_price` in particular because it wasn't included in the end `SELECT` result however, `tbl_direct_fuel.status` was being used in `WHERE` might have some impact. But after constructing the possible query, I assume that in this example, it's not required to include `tbl_direct_fuel.status` at all. Anyway, that's for you to figure out.